# Проблемы с отступами при выводе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем дня

```
$zaproz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'",$db);
$massiv = mysql_fetch_array($zaproz);
echo $massiv[1];
```

При echo текст (textarea) выводится без отступов (переносов на др. строку), в самом же phpmyadmin отступы есть. Как именно прописать вывод текста в textarea с отступами?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Текст в виде html? Или просто текст? Вероятней всего по описанию это просто текст. Значит нужно заменить переносы строки на тег <br/>. Сделать это можно с помощью функции nl2br();

```
$zaproz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'",$db);
$massiv = mysql_fetch_array($zaproz);
echo nl2br($massiv[1]);
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Спасибо про nl2br($model->information ) не знал )